# How can I parse a string into a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, guid, entity-framework-6

I'm writing an Entity Framework LINQ query in which I want to parse a string into a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER (aka GUID) as part of the `WHERE` clause:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Find(Guid guid)
{
    return dbContext
        .Users
        .Where(user => Guid.Parse(user.GuidText) == guid);
}
```

I know this is possible in SQL because I've tested it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE CAST(GuidText AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) = @guid;
```

However, I haven't found a way to generate the `CAST` part. I've tried:

1. `(Guid)user.GuidText`, which generates a compiler error.
2. `Convert.ToGuid(user.GuidText)`, but this method doesn't exist.
3. `Guid.Parse(user.GuidText)`, but this causes Entity Framework to generate an error when it translates the LINQ query.
4. `new Guid(user.GuidText)`, but this causes Entity Framework to generate an error when it translates the LINQ query.
5. `(Guid)Convert.ChangeType(user.GuidText, typeof(Guid))`, but this causes Entity Framework to generate an error when it translates the LINQ query.
6. `SqlGuid.Parse(user.GuidText)`, but this causes Entity Framework to generate an error when it translates the LINQ query.

How can I achieve this? I'm willing to embed SQL in the code as a last resort.

Comment: What about user.GuidText == guid.ToString() or user.GuidText == guid + string.Empty

Comment: @Colin, that doesn't account for the different possible string formats of GUIDs, whereas a semantic comparison does. I'd prefer to write something that will translate into reasonable SQL. Also, the `ToString` translation fails at run-time.

Comment: @Colin, I should clarify that the `ToString` translation only works if it's performed outside of the query.

Comment: Why do you need the cast? if your db keeps string why dont you compare the value with a string?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau, because the value is a GUID stored as a string and I want to do a semantic GUID comparison.

Comment: *Why* is it being stored as a string in the first place? The name of the column suggests that it's *only* used to store a guid, so why is it not being stored as a native `uniqueidentifier` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the name of the column in the code I provided is to make it clear that it contains a string representation of a GUID. In the real system I'm working on, the name is different. The reason it's stored as a string is the format/type of the identifier depends on which of multiple third-party systems the application integrates with. I've used a string instead of a `varbinary` because the database is intended to be accessible by administrators of the application, and I consider strings more human-friendly than binary data.

Comment: I've created a work item for this [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1865). I recommend you vote for it if you also want this functionaliy.

Comment: Create a scalar UDF that converts the string to a guid and call that.

Comment: @Magnus, that's a valid solution, but I don't like the idea of modifying a database just to work-around an application code bug.

Answer (score 1):

in case you have a mature reason for doing the cast - you can create a VIEWbased on your User table and convert your GUID text to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

```
SELECT ..., CAST(GuidText AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), ...
```

Than refering the view in your code you should be able to do the comparison without a casting

Answer (score 1):

EF runtime actually supports converting from a string to a GUID as a cast operation, but as you find out there is currently no way of expressing this in LINQ that we support.

The best workaround that I can think of is to use Entity SQL:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var query = objectContext.CreateQuery<User>(
  "SELECT VALUE u FROM Context.Users AS u WHERE CAST(u.GuidText AS System.Guid) = @guid", 
  new ObjectParameter("guid", guid));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without hard-coding the name of the table and column?

Comment: That might require a bit of reflection code, e.g. you can replace the call to CreateQuery<T> with objectContext.CreateObjectSet<User>().Where("CAST(it.GuidText AS System.Guid) = @guid", new ObjectParameter("guid", guid)) to avoid hardcoding the table. You will still have to use MakeGenericMethod to fill in the generic argument and probably get the name of the property from the PropertyInfo in order to produce the Entity SQL string.

Comment: By the way, my take on this is that Guid.Parse(string) and new Guid(string) would be nice things to support in LINQ to Entities for this scenario. It is only not super high priority but we would take a contribution. The bug is marked as UpForGrabs: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1865.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that *should* produce the equivalent functionality by using a string comparison instead of a GUID comparison:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Find(Guid guid)
{
    var idString = guid.ToString("N");

    return dbContext
        .Users
        .Where(user => user.UserDirectoryUserId
            .Replace("{", String.Empty)
            .Replace("}", String.Empty)
            .Replace("-", String.Empty)
            .Replace(",", String.Empty)
            .Replace("0x", String.Empty)
            .ToLower()
            == idString
        );
}
```

Obviously this isn't an ideal solution since it will generate ugly SQL rather instead of the desired SQL.

Comment: It would be better to format the incoming guid parameter to match the column string guid format.